# Jquery Masking returning Float/Int Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

how can i returned back the original value of the input that masked using jquery masking plugin ?

this case, i'm using money currency masking. if i get the value using jQuery, it returning string, not float/int.

how can i returned it back to original value ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
  var mon = $('.money').val();
  console.log(mon);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="money" value="30000">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.cleanVal()` on the element. Read the section **Getting a masked value programmatically** of [this link](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
  var mon = $('.money').cleanVal();
  console.log(mon);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="money" value="30000">
```

Textboxes always return string values. You have to parse it as number manually using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `parseFloat(string)` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
  var mon = parseFloat($('.money').val());
  console.log(mon);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="money" value="30000">
```